# editing build-in layout - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar-compat

I am using `Action Bar Compact`, is it possible to edit its build-in layout `abc_list_menu_item_layout`.

Because this line

```
v = activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE).
    inflate(R.layout.abc_list_menu_item_layout, null);
```

throws this

```
Can't convert to dimension: type=0x2
                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
                at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5768)
```

Comment: No, you should not edit the layout files that come with the appcompat library.

Comment: Why are you manually inflating this layout?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice because I have a list view on which I call an adapter (`ArrayAdapter`). But perhaps I shouldn't, I am new to android

Comment: I still don't understand why you are manually inflating an action bar layout file. What does your listview have to do with the action bar?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice because I need some list items, so I declare in my resources some `<ListView android:id="@+id/someList">` and then the problem is that my IDE does not suggest me `R.layout.simple_list_item_1"` but only suggests some resources files, from which I grab one that provides list items, and the one I find it should fit is `abc_list_menu_item_layout`. (I call `listView.setAdapter(new SomeAdapter(getActivity(), getResources(), R.layout.abc_list_menu_item_layout, null, user, someViewPager));`)

Comment: A **menu** item is not the same as a **list** item. You should use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` instead.